# Batch file to flush redis client locally

Tags: batch-file, redis, redis-cli, redis-server

I want to flush redis server through batch file so I am trying to create batch file with following command but it doesn't work for me.

```
SET REDIS_PATH=C:\Redis
"%REDIS_PATH%\redis-cli" FLUSHALL
```

Comment: You say it "doesn't work" but you don't go into detail. How do you know it has failed? What error do you see? Does the command work correctly when you run it directly from the command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Solved My self. I have created a shortcut to desktop and edited properties.